# Count Foreign Key table rows in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework

In SQL I am able to do something like this:

SELECT colA, colB, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ForeignTable WHERE colA = TableA.colA)
FROM TableA

Is something like this possible in EF Core?

Just to be clear with Models

```
public class TableA
{
    public string colA { get; set; }
    public string colB { get; set; }
}

public class ForeignTable
{
    public string colA { get; set; }

    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. See [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships), and more specifically *collection navigation properties*. With such property it's simply a matter of `obj.Collection.Count()`

Comment: Thanks but I think the issue is I want to get the count of the Child table from the Parent. I found a way doing it with GroupJoin that works but I doubt it is the optimal way.

Comment: It's exactly the same as using collection navigation property  inside IQueryable query. The generated SQL query would be one and the same, just using the navigation property is more convenient.

Comment: If you look at my added Models. I have a navigation property on the Foreign table but not on TableA, If I add a navigation property on TableA to ForeignTable how does it know which column to join on?

Comment: Okay, apologies and thanks. I see if I add the navigation property and just Include that in the query it works perfectly. Thanks for your assistance in this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ivan Stoev, the right answer is just to include a Navigation property in TableA to ForeignTable and ensuring that table is .Include() in the query.

The below is for reference, way more complicated...

```
var data = from q in _context.TableA.
GroupJoin(_context.ForeignTable, i => i.colA, j => j.FcolA,
(i,j) => new {TableA = i, ForeignTable = j}
select new TableA
{
colA = q.TableA.colA,
colB = q.TableA.colB,
count = q.ForeignTable.Count()
};
```